# Typescript optional object property only works with union of void?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

I've been using Typescript for a while and just ran into this interesting behaviour. I want to create an optional object property on an interface that is type safe. The first method I tried was this:

```
type StrNumDict = { 
  [key: string]: number;
};

interface Bar {
  bar: string;
  foo?: StrNumDict;
}

const y: Bar = {
  bar: 'xxx'
}

console.log(y.foo.x);
```

The problem with this is the typescript compiler doesn't raise an error when I do `console.log(y.foo.x);` (it should as x may be undefined)

So I had a play around and did the following (I need this to be typed so I can't use `object`):

```
interface Bar {
  bar: string;
  foo?: void | StrNumDict;
}

console.log(y.foo.x);
```

Typescript raises the error correctly as `'x' does not exist on type 'void | StrNumDict'` and I have to check `x` exists

Could someone explain to my why this works? Is it correct? Why does ? not work correctly on an object property type?

Comment: Are you using [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks)?

Comment: Yep that did the trick! Was disabled in my tsconfig. Interesting that doing a union with void makes it work all the time.